# Creación automática de un diccionario

Tags: c#, lista, diccionarios

Sé que esta pregunta es muy básica pero estoy intentando crear un diccionario pero me gustaría que se hiciera automáticamente, en este necesito que cada variable de la lista deck progresivamente sumando uno. A continuación la lista y una demostración de como quiero que se vea el diccionario. (No quiero simplificar la forma en la que la lista deck es creada porque se que se puede hacer de una forma mas eficiente).

```
void Start()
{
    var cartasOro = new List<string>() { "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6", "O7", "OJ", "OQ", "OK" };
    var cartasCopa = new List<string>() { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "CJ", "CQ", "CK" };
    var cartasEspada = new List<string>() { "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "EJ", "EQ", "EK" };
    var cartasBasto = new List<string>() { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "BJ", "BQ", "BK" };
    var deck = new List<string>() {};

    deck.AddRange(cartasOro);
    deck.AddRange(cartasCopa);
    deck.AddRange(cartasEspada);
    deck.AddRange(cartasBasto);

    Dictionary<string, int> cardToIndex = new()
    {
        { "O1", 1},
        { "O2", 2},
        { "O3", 3},
        { "O4", 4},
        { "O5", 5},
        { "O6", 6},
        { "O7", 7},
        { "O8", 8},
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n = 0;
Dictionary<string, int> cardToIndex = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(var d in deck)
{
    n++;
    cardToIndex[d] = n;
}
```

Se crea la **variable n** que servirá de índice al diccionario, y se declara además el diccionario. Posteriormente se ejecuta un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá todos los elementos de tu lista, dentro de este ciclo se incrementa en **1** la **variable n**, y finalmente se van añadiendo al diccionario cada elemento de la lista con su respectivo índice.